# React: Mutating inner stuff of a context object without using setState - is that ok?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, use-context

I do have an Open Layers map inside the context of my React app.

```
const {
    map
} = useContext(MapContext);
```

When I do stuff on the map (e.g. zooming, shifting the center) I am mutating the map object indirectly using the Open Layers functions like e.g. so:

```
map.getView().setZoom(map.getView().getZoom() + 1) //Zooming in by 1 unit
```

So the map object changes internally.

I've learned though that changing a state or a context in React *requires without any exception* calling a function like setState (in this case it would be called setMap). The map already gets mutated by the Open Layers internal functions though. I do not need to call sth like setMap.

Is this actually ok or bad practise?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call `setState()` you won't get component update events. For React, your component hasn't been updated.

Is it bad practice to store information in the state that shouldn't really be there? There are better ways to do this, but nothing too bad will happen.

I also invite you to consider trying https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers (of which I am the author) which solves exactly those types of problems by encapsulating the internal OpenLayers state in React components.